# Stripe.net How to link customers to managed accounts?

Tags: c#, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I am working on a platform that will have multiple managed accounts.  Then those accounts will have customers created under them.  I can create either of them using the stripe.net, but I'm not sure how to link them (Or is that done behind the scenes?)

I realize I could manually execute the charges and add the charge.Destination field to the StripeChargeCreateOptions, but then I would have to manually schedule the charges instead of using the plan.

I'm also wondering how I can check the account balances of the managed accounts.  From the API:

> "Retrieves the current account balance, based on the authentication that was used to make the request."

```
var balanceService = new StripeBalanceService();
StripeBalance response = balanceService.Get();
```

I'm not sure how to set that to use the managed accounts authentication.

In other words I want to have customers get charged based on their plan and have that added to the managed account's balance that they were created under.  Then have that balance transfer to their bank account on a schedule (which I see is configurable on the managed account object).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question you simple need to add:

```
StripeRequestOptions account = new StripeRequestOptions();
account.StripeConnectAccountId = accountId;
```

And pass it into the customer create function.  You can also pass it into the balance service to get the account balance.